# How to return error message from JavaScript in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to developed custom validation on input controls. For this I am planning to write attribute directives and link directives to the controls.

```
    <input validpc type="text" id="pc" class="form-control" name="PC" ng-model="answers.pc"  required>
<span class="form-error" ng-show="submitted && DTOstep1[que.QuestionData._attributeName].$error.required && DTOstep1[que.QuestionData._attributeName].$invalid">The field is required.</span>
```

like validpc is a directive.

this will check many many criteria and will return error accordingly. like if entered value is
0, error message can be : 0 is not a valid entry.
1, error message can be : Number should be greater than 50.

if input is 100 then it should return true. Here criteria is wrote only for example purposes.

Here I am stuck how to write directive in this way which will used for vallidation and send error messages. I dont want to write so many ng-messages html tag in index file.

```
function validpc() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'text-control-dir',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        console.log('here in validPc');
        }
      }
```

Comment: You can use this module for custom validations. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate

Comment: This does not answer my question.